# Ubuntu 17.04. install driver for USB Ethernet Adapter

Tags: usb, ethernet, adapter

Need to install a USB Ethernet Adapter (lsusb string below)

*Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.*

I have got four files by the manufacturer:

/home/sergey/Downloads/RTL8152/LINUX Andriod/50-usb-realtek-net.rules
/home/sergey/Downloads/RTL8152/LINUX Andriod/compatibility.h
/home/sergey/Downloads/RTL8152/LINUX Andriod/Makefile
/home/sergey/Downloads/RTL8152/LINUX Andriod/r8152.c

**Q1:** Do I need to install these files above somehow?

**Q2:** If Q1 is negative, How to check the Adapter / make it work?

**Note:** The main goal is to connect a Wi-Fi hub (Zyxell KEENETIC) via the above Adapter. Indication on the hub shows no network connection via the Adapter.

Please advise.
SK

EDIT for @chili555

TY for your prompt answer. Pls see the findings below.

```
sergey@home-X200CA:~$ lsmod | grep r8152
r8152                  49152  0
mii                    16384  2 usbnet,r8152
sergey@home-X200CA:~$ ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::da50:e6ff:fe9e:f905  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:50:e6:9e:f9:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 618782  bytes 742610979 (742.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1787  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 441907  bytes 64009887 (64.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  
enx00e04c362984: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:4c:36:29:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6098  bytes 2693946 (2.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6098  bytes 2693946 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 5.35.51.212  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 5.35.0.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 458293  bytes 537885941 (537.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 337967  bytes 41480878 (41.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
sergey@home-X200CA:~$ dmesg | grep r8152
[   16.811429] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[   17.019410] r8152 3-1.3:1.0 eth0: v1.08.8
[   19.889560] r8152 3-1.3:1.0 enx00e04c362984: renamed from eth0
sergey@home-X200CA:~$ dmesg | grep inp350
sergey@home-X200CA:~$ 
sergey@home-X200CA:~$ dmesg | grep inp3s0
sergey@home-X200CA:~$
```

Suppose I used the wrong Interface. Please advise.

Comment: The problem was with the cable.

Answer (score 4):

**A1**: No, you needn't install the driver. It is already included in Ubuntu 17.04. It is *r8152*. From the module aliases:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/r8152.ko
version:        v1.08.8
license:        GPL
description:    Realtek RTL8152/RTL8153 Based USB Ethernet Adapters
author:         Realtek linux nic maintainers <nic_swsd@realtek.com>
srcversion:     382765E0356A7F7FA08EF4C
<snip>
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8152d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc06ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8152d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc*ip*in*
<snip>
```

**A2**: Insert the device. Check to see if the driver loaded:

```
lsmod | grep r8152
```

Check to see if an interface is created:

```
ifconfig
```

Check to see if there are any clues in the log:

```
dmesg | grep r8152
dmesg | grep <interface_you_found>
```

For example, `ifconfig` says that my ethernet interface is enp0s25. Therefore, looking for clues, I'd check:

```
dmesg | grep enp0s25
```

Post your findings in an edit to your question and I will edit this answer to add troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 0):

After studying the info according to the recommendations I decided to check the Ethernet connection between the hub and the Adapter. The problem was in the cable. Now the hub is responding. Thanks for usefull help.

Best,
SK