# Install mainline kernel in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, 17.04

I'm trying to install Kernel v4.13-rc6 because [I've been told](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948611/ubuntu-17-04-install-driver-for-ethernet-adapter) it has the driver for my ethernet interface. However I have never dealt with custom kernels before so consider the answer to my question is possibly obvious.

As I understood from [Ubuntuusers Wiki: Mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Mainline-Kernel/) I should download the according .deb file from [PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13-rc6/) and install it.

**linux-headers-4.13.0-*_all.deb works:**

```
engor@engorx1:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6_4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 281073 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6_4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6 (4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831) over (4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6 (4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831) ...
```

**linux-headers-4.13.0-*-generic_4.13.0-*_amd64.deb fails:**

```
engor@engorx1:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6-generic_4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 281073 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6-generic_4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6-generic (4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831) over (4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6-generic (4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-041300rc6-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-041300rc6-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-041300rc6-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.043.02/build/make.log for more information.
```

/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.043.02/build/make.log can be found [here](https://0bin.net/paste/YrjGxf8xJuS7sIKj#sUKWTY9Eb7csILJfSBOs7K2k2Yo+j61ZCUJH1Qnsvm+).

**EDIT:** Not both packages install without errors. Thanks to Pilot6's answer. Still the second part of my question remains unanswered.

**Question:** How can I get grub to boot with the new kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `r8168-dkms` that is incompatible with this kernel

```
sudo apt purge r8168-dkms
```

And you need to install

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13-rc6/linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6_4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831_all.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13-rc6/linux-headers-4.13.0-041300rc6-generic_4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13-rc6/linux-image-4.13.0-041300rc6-generic_4.13.0-041300rc6.201708201831_amd64.deb

Comment: Mr. Pilot6 you are my hero of the day!
Maybe you can also tell me how to get grub to use that new kernel?

Comment: Grub will use the new kernel automatically. But it looks that you installed only headers. You need to install the image. It is actually the "real" kernel package.

Comment: Installed   linux-image-4.13.0- * -generic_4.13.0- * _amd64.de and now it worked. Thank you for your help and patience.