# Dell XPS15 Ubuntu 18.04 ethernet not connecting

Tags: networking, 18.04, dell, ethernet

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18 on my dell xps 15, to my surprise wifi is working perfectly but I cannot get wired ethernet to connect.

The output of lshw is:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:fc:1f:33
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-38-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=10.168.85.54 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:144 memory:ed200000-ed3fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx34298f9231a4
       serial: 34:29:8f:92:31:a4
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

So I think the problem is that for the Ethernet interface no product is found!

As the dell XPS 15 does not have a ethernet port I am using a USB C adapter. The adapter is a 10-in-1 hub ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07GDHD3VC/ref=s9_acsd_hps_bw_c_x_1_w](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07GDHD3VC)) and the output of lsusb -v is posted here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TNnF7FSYby/

More diagnostic:

```
> lsmod | grep r8152
r8152                  61440  0
mii                    16384  2 usbnet,r8152

>  ifconfig
enx34298f9231a4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 34:29:8f:92:31:a4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 63  bytes 11158 (11.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 19788  bytes 37449974 (37.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19788  bytes 37449974 (37.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.169.130.213  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 10.169.135.255
        inet6 fe80::539a:877a:c301:4d3f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9c:b6:d0:fc:1f:33  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1913953  bytes 2450518697 (2.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1090058  bytes 119134130 (119.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

> dmesg | grep enx34298f9231a4
[    8.784167] r8152 4-1.3.1:1.0 enx34298f9231a4: renamed from eth0
[   10.103739] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx34298f9231a4: link is not ready
[   10.109374] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx34298f9231a4: link is not ready
[   12.310544] r8152 4-1.3.1:1.0 enx34298f9231a4: carrier on
[   12.310558] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx34298f9231a4: link becomes ready
[ 6455.709355] r8152 4-1.3.1:1.0 enx34298f9231a4: carrier off
[11793.133656] r8152 4-1.3.1:1.0 enx34298f9231a4: Stop submitting intr, status -71
[11836.892211] r8152 4-1.3.1:1.0 enx34298f9231a4: renamed from eth0
[11836.933975] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx34298f9231a4: link is not ready
[11836.938515] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx34298f9231a4: link is not ready
[11840.292564] r8152 4-1.3.1:1.0 enx34298f9231a4: carrier on
[11840.292591] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx34298f9231a4: link becomes ready
```

Thank you!

Comment: As this is a USB adapter, the first question is "what USB adapter?" What does `lsusb -v` print?

Comment: It looks like this uses the Realtek RTL8152 chipset, and should be supported in Ubuntu 18.04 using the r8152 linux module. Could you try the steps listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942274/ubuntu-17-04-install-driver-for-usb-ethernet-adapter) to see if if the module is getting auto-loaded and creating an ethernet interface?

Comment: @StuartCaie I followed the steps and posted all the results!

Comment: From the diagnostic, it looks like the ethernet interface is there: `enx34298f9231a4`, and it works correctly -  it received some packets. However, it is not configured with an IP address. You should find this interface in the system networking settings, and if it is not already ticked, set "Connect Automatically" and under IPv4 set "Automatic (DHCP)"